# Custom functionality working in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: oracle-apex, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I have an oracle apex application, version 18.2 and in it I have many custom functionalities including ones for custom file saving and video and audio preview. Recently we have gotten word that some of the functionalities do not work properly and after further review have discovered that it is to do with the browser. Using Firefox everything works properly, but using Chrome or even Safari, some things don't work.

The problems we have is with downloading files and with previewing video and audio. The file downloading and preview is handled by blueimp jquery file upload and processing plugins and a node.js server on the backend because our files are stored outside the database.

The problems we are facing is that preview doesent work on chrome, it works just fine on firefox, but on chrome, the popup to play the file shows up but the file appears to be 0 seconds long and thus does not play.

Another problem we are facing is downloading the files, when we enabled https and got a certificate and all that, if I connect via ssh and access the site through localhost, everything works. But if I access the site through the domain or ip, and not through localhost, then left clicking the file link downloads an empty file, as in the file exists, but its 0KB. Right clicking and opening in a new tab or new window downloads the file properly. And this problem is again only in Chrome, and apparently Safari.

This problem is above me, I have tried again and again to understand what the hell is going on, but I am utterly lost. So any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the browser console? Does the functionality you're using apply to all browser types? Check at http://caniuse.com/

Comment: @Scott No, no errors were found anywhere. I even put chrome in debug mode and checked the massive logs, and didnt really find anything that is different in there, although I dont really understand the log perfectly.
As far as caniuse goes, I dont really know what functionality this would be. I am in fact just maintaining the application, and didnt develop it. But even the developer just took existing blueimp plugins and made them work. So I dont know what functionality this would be using.

Comment: This plug-in? https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload#desktop-browsers It seems to support older browsers... At any rate, this would be very hard to figure out without some kind of sample app that reproduces the issue. Are you able to provide that? If not, you may need to reach out to a consultant to help you. Have you heard of askMax? https://askmax.solutions/

Comment: @DanMcGhan yeah, this plug in. A sample app is not gonna be possible because it would require the entire environment. Its a clusterfuck of code on the machines, a node.js server and two conjoined applications. The dev environment isnt even fully functioning because of the clusterfuck(its just an apex app with none of the clusterfuck backend)